# unrecognized option attr-defined in mypy

Tags: python, mypy

Hello I am using oracledb.NUMBER, etc... and when I execute mypy I got the following error:

```
Module has not attribute "NUMBER"
```

I set into mypy.ini the following options in order to skip that error, but didn't work.

```
[mypy]
disable-error-code = attr-defined

[mypy]
disable-error-code = "attr-defined"

[mypy-oracle.*]
disable-error-code = "attr-defined"
```

how can I ignore it?

thanks

Comment: `# type: ignore[attr-defined]`, you definitely don't want to ignore this error globally...

Comment: I only want to ignore for oracledb

Comment: In ini file, the options are spelled with underscores (so it should be `disable_error_code = attr-defined`). Please also read [the documentation about this](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_codes.html#per-module-enabling-disabling-error-codes)